# How to get URL in CefSharp browser

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

How to get URL in CefSharp browser?

I want to make button for copy to clipboard.

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/57.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_Address.htm

Comment: WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

The ChromiumWebbrowser browser object has an Address attribute. Refer to this in an on click call back that you pass to a copy to clipboard handler.